# Unknown mailing status on few mailings recipients

Tags: civimail

Since the 4.7.8 update to 4.7.10 and 4.7.10 to 4.7.12 recently some mails are not reaching their recipients. If I look at the Mailing Detail Report the Successful Deliveries rate is between 90% and 100% and the status of the not received mails are "Unknown".

To see these mails on the report I have to filter as status "-any-" because there is no possibility to do it with the status "unknown".

Has anyone encountered the same problem? What may be due?

**Edit**

I investigated a little more and I see that "Unknown" status appears when there is no record on the civicrm_mailing_event_bounce table AND when there is no record on the civicrm_mailing_event_delivered. Then, it seems that for some users, there isn't registering the delivery of the mail.

<del>I begin to suspect that the problem is related with an issue of inconsitency caches of the mailing recipients groups.</del>

**Edit 2**

I found on logs messages like `[info] CiviMail will not send an empty mail body, Skipping: xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx` corresponding to the contacts with mailing status marked as "Unknown".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed for 4.7.15

PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9463

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on this other question: [Mail not send if preferred_mail_format is NULL](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14954/mail-not-send-if-preferred-mail-format-is-null).

The original problem seems reported and solved first on [CRM-18037](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18037). But also persist and dragged in later versions as reported on [CRM-18157](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18157), [CRM-19135](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19135), [CRM-19442](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19442), [CRM-19423](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19423).

Otherwise in the latest fixes upgrade scripts that converts 'NULL' `preferred_mail_formats` to 'Both' are not executed. If I'm on right, last  time is executed is in [4.7.7 upgrade](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/4.7.7.mysql.tpl#L61).

Meanwhile to solve current inconsistencies it seems suficient to execute the following script on the database:

`` UPDATE `civicrm_contact` SET `preferred_mail_format` = 'Both' WHERE `preferred_mail_format` IS NULL; ``

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19685