# Delivery mail status - unknown

Tags: civimail, email, mailing

Is the delivery mail status 'unknown' a case of Civi not having sent the mail out at all and is still effectively in the queue to send?

Having lots of problems sending bulk mailing e.g. where only 30 out of 78 emails are successful and the rest set to unknown (as opposed to legitimate bounces)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this related question [Unknown mailing status on few mailings recipients](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15369/unknown-mailing-status-on-few-mailings-recipients) to check if it fits to your case.

What version of civicrm do you use?

Comment: Hi yes checked this... activities are not be recorded for Unknowns (there are records for successes). We are not running the FetchBounce job yet.  We have mail runs recording successes and failures. The mail job status gets stuck on 'running'  and looks like it might be a single email address that sends civi in a loop.  We have had mailing with 100% successful deliveries (including capturing bouncebacks on our mail relay currently hosted with 1&1)

Comment: We also picked up the NULL issue where the primary email address was flagged in the interface but not populated on the backend. Primairy email address only populated correctly when the email popup was opened and saved. Believe this affected recerds that were imported as opposed to added manually.  We had the same issue of NULLs on is_deceased. All now rectified. There was no issue with mail_format NULLs.

Comment: Civi 4.7.19 (Wordpress)